# Acumatica How to pass User Defined Fields in Processing Forms

Tags: acumatica, user-defined

I would like to fill 2 fields in the purchase order from sales order marked for PO (Purchase To Order) (one from SOOrderExt, the second from SOLineExt).
How to do this with the Processing Form "Create Purchase Order" (PO.50.50.00)

[image: Create Purchase Order Form]

Comment: What do you mean filling these fields? Do you want to populate their value during the PO Create process?

Comment: Yes I want to populate their value during the PO Create process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `FindOrCreatePOOrder` and `FindOrCreatePOLine` on `POCreate` graph.
In `FindOrCreatePOOrder` the new poOrder is not in the cache yet, it is just a simple object, so you can't get it's extension. You have to set Agence on your new PO in `FindOrCreatePOLine`.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace PX.Objects.PO 
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    public class POCreateExt : PXGraphExtension<POCreate>
    {
        private int? AgenceFromSO;
    
        public delegate POOrder FindOrCreatePOOrderDelegate(DocumentList<POOrder> created, POOrder previousOrder,
            POFixedDemand demand, SOOrder soorder, POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3 soline, bool requireSingleProject);

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual POOrder FindOrCreatePOOrder(DocumentList<POOrder> created, POOrder previousOrder,
            POFixedDemand demand, SOOrder soorder, POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3 soline, bool requireSingleProject,
            FindOrCreatePOOrderDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            var poOrder = baseMethod.Invoke(created, previousOrder, demand, soorder, soline, requireSingleProject);
                    
            // Save UsrAgence for FindOrCreatePOLine
            var soOrderExt = soorder?.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
            AgenceFromSO = soOrderExt?.UsrAgence;
        
            return poOrder;
        }

        public delegate POLine FindOrCreatePOLineDelegate(POOrderEntry docgraph, DocumentList<POLine> ordered,
            string orderType,
            POFixedDemand demand, POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3 soline);

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual POLine FindOrCreatePOLine(POOrderEntry docgraph, DocumentList<POLine> ordered, string orderType,
            POFixedDemand demand, POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3 soline, FindOrCreatePOLineDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            // Set Agence on header here
            var poOrderExt = docgraph.Document.Current.GetExtension<POOrderExt>();
            poOrderExt.UsrAgence = AgenceFromSO;
        
            POLine poLine = baseMethod.Invoke(docgraph, ordered, orderType, demand, soline);
            SOLine soLineActual = SOLine.PK.Find(docgraph, soline.OrderType, soline.OrderNbr, soline.LineNbr);
            SOLineExt soLineExt = soLineActual.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();

            if (poLine != null)
            {
                decimal? price = soLineExt.UsrVendorPrice;
                docgraph.Transactions.SetValueExt<POLine.curyUnitCost>(poLine, price);
            }

            return poLine;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have an error : GetItemExtensionFailed when clicking 'PROCESS'

Comment: In which function? FindOrCreatePOOrder or FindOrCreatePOLine? Also for which line? PO or SO?

Comment: In both functions, I put each part in comment and I have the same result. I've just modified the code because I don't need POLineExt. poLine.CuryUnitCost = soLineExt.UsrVendorPrice;

Comment: Ok, then please update your question with the source code of your DAC and Graph extensions, and I will try to reproduce the issue. Without that I need to debug your code blind, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: I found a solution for the POLine by adding SOLine solineactual = SOLine.PK.Find(docgraph, soline.OrderType, soline.OrderNbr, soline.LineNbr); after poLine = baseMethod.Invoke and changing var soLineExt =>   SOLineExt soLineExt = solineactual.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(); The problem seems to be the same for  FindOrCreatePOOrder but I cannot call docgraph in SOOrder.PK.Find

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you without the source code.

Comment: Please find my updated answer. I tested it on my local instance and it transferred Agence from SO to PO.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe it's due to Acumatica french version?

Comment: No, it should not make any difference here, it is standard Acumatica behaviour.